# Custom TSLint rule to warning on a method invocation

Tags: typescript, lint, tslint, linter

I want to start preventing people from invoking a method in TypeScript that I already deprecated. For that, I would like to have a custom TSLint rule to show a warning every time someone tries to use that method.

I have researched on how to create my own TSLint rules, but I haven't figure out how to specifically show a warning when a method is invoked yet.

Could you please provide me some guidance with this?

Thank you in advance.